# Parsing a HashMap Json .fromJson

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, hashmap

This might be a novice question. I am having trouble with parsing my .json into a hashmap I could write the json file easily which is how I know It was written correctly, but loading it in im getting a error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.johnny.gamerpg.inventoryController$Weapon> has no zero argument constructor
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created (non-static member class): com.johnny.gamerpg.inventoryController$Weapon
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ReflectionException: Could not instantiate instance of class: com.johnny.gamerpg.inventoryController$Weapon
```

I believe I do have a zero constructor and those classes set up correctly because I am using them to write the .json.

Here are those classes.

```
public class item {
    public String name;
    public item() {}
}

public class Weapon extends item {
    int damageMin = 9;
    int damageMax = 15;
    int priceBuy = 1;
    int priceSell = 2;

    public Weapon() {}
}

public class Sword extends Weapon{

    public Sword() {}
}

public class Dagger extends Weapon{

    public Dagger() {}
}

private FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("items.json");
private HashMap<String, item> items = new HashMap<String, item>();

private void load(){
    Json json = new Json();
    items = json.fromJson(HashMap.class, file);
}
```

I have searched around and have not found anything exactly like this. So that probably means im doing something silly! Anyways here is the Json file im reading in and thanks any advice would be amazing.

```
{
"SwordOfDeath": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.inventoryController$Sword",
    "name": "Sword of Death",
    "damageMax": 15,
    "damageMin": 2,
    "priceBuy": 1,
    "priceSell": 2
},
"DaggerOfDeath": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.inventoryController$Dagger",
    "name": "Dagger of Death",
    "damageMax": 15,
    "damageMin": 2,
    "priceBuy": 1,
    "priceSell": 2
}
}
```

thanks!

Edit: 
Imports,
    package com.johnny.gamerpg;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter;

import java.util.HashMap;
```

Comment: Could you show your import statements?

Comment: @John **Updated!**

Comment: And are your java classes all in the same file or separate files?

Comment: @John They are all within the same file!

Comment: @johnnyboy5566 see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a close look at the errors, you'll see that they refer to a "`(non-static member class)`"- put your classes in their own files, and it should work.

Another thing you can do (which will help you if you want to use GWT) is start using the libGDX data structures like [`ObjectMap`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.html)- they seem to work better with the libGDX parsers and are optimized for games.

Finally, it looks like you're about to create classes for every weapon in your game- you might want to consider keeping your "weapon" class and then passing it data to make it into a sword or dagger or staff or AK47 or whatever. In software development we call it "[Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)".

Comment: I was going to make a class for every **different** type of weapon!

Answer (score 1):

According to the stacktrace, `Weapon` is nested class inside `inventoryController`. According to your code, it's not marked as `static` , but as a public inner class.

That means that `inventoryController` needs to be instantiated in order to instantiate `Weapon` and that's why you're getting that zero-param constructor exception

By the way, `inventoryController` should be `InventoryController`

Declare it as static and there you have it :)

Comment: This is also a completely valid **answer**. I just used @John because he was already working with me, and also I liked the idea of splitting the file up!